# Output spacing error

Tags: python, output, space

i have coded this program which will take in a user sentence, replace the words in the user sentence with their position and display the new sentence.
However when i run it the program works fine but if the sentence contains more than 9 different words, position that contain more digits are shown separately. here is the code:

```
UserSentence = input("Please enter sentence: \n")
UniqueWords = []
NewSentence = "" 

splitsentence = UserSentence 
splitsentence = splitsentence.lower().split() 

for word in splitsentence: 
    if word not in UniqueWords: 
        UniqueWords.append(word) 

for word in splitsentence:
    NewSentence += str(UniqueWords.index(word)+1) 

NewSentence = ' '.join(NewSentence) 
print (NewSentence)
```

if i enter this sentence:
     "this sentence contains more than ten words but the output is wrong i do not know what to say"
The expected output should be:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
```

But instead i get all the numbers all together even double digits numbers are separated by space:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 3 1 4 1 5 1 6 1 7 1 8 1 9
```

can somebody help me to fix this?

Comment: Try `print (NewSentence)` before the call to `join()`.

Comment: i already tried but i still get the output but clustered like this 12345678910111213141516171819

Comment: make NewSentence a `list` and append to it `NewSentence.append(str(UniqueWords.index(word)+1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `' '.join(NewSentence)` when your sentence looks like this: `1234...111213` so `join()` splits the `NewSentence` into its individual characters. You should instead add a space to the `NewSentence` after each loop, instead of calling `join()`. This should be what you want:

```
UserSentence = input("Please enter sentence: \n")
UniqueWords = []
NewSentence = ""

splitsentence = UserSentence
splitsentence = splitsentence.lower().split()

for word in splitsentence:
    if word not in UniqueWords:
        UniqueWords.append(word)

for word in splitsentence:
    NewSentence += str(UniqueWords.index(word)+1) + " "

print(NewSentence)
```

Comment: Hope you don't mind, but this is identical to my answer... but i upvoted it anyway

Comment: @Liam you submitted the answer after I did :||. BTW thanks for +1

Comment: Oh dear. Be nice everyone!

Answer (score 3):

I think you're over-thinking the problem.

If you want unique values (with order not mattering), use `set()`.

```
sentence = input("Please enter sentence: \n")
words = sentence.lower().split() 
unique_words = set(words)
```

Then, you just are wanting a list of numbers? The words themselves don't really matter, only the size of that collection.

```
new_sentence = range(1, len(unique_words)+1)

print(' '.join(map(str, new_sentence)))
```

Output

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
```

---

If the ordering & words did matter, then continue using a list, but you can do that final output more succinctly

```
new_sentence = [ str(unique_words.index(word)+1) for word in unique_words ]
new_sentence = ' '.join(new_sentence)
```

Answer (score 1):

there was an error at line 13:

```
NewSentence += str(UniqueWords.index(word)+1)
```

you should add a spacer and once done your code should look like this:

```
UserSentence = raw_input("Please enter sentence: \n")
UniqueWords = []
NewSentence = "" 

splitsentence = UserSentence 
splitsentence = splitsentence.lower().split() 

for word in splitsentence: 
    if word not in UniqueWords: 
        UniqueWords.append(word) 

for word in splitsentence:
    NewSentence += str(UniqueWords.index(word)+1)+" "

print NewSentence
```

Answer (score 1):

Like the other answers suggest, you're over-complicating. You need to print out a string with a set of incremental numbers separated by a space, one number for each word in the sentence.

First, get the length of the sentence in words:

```
length = len(UserSentence.split())
```

Then, construct a string over that range:

```
newSentence = ' '.join([str(i+1) for i in range(length)])
```

*(the argument of the `join` method is a list comprehension; which allows you to construct lists in one line)*

Then, print it:

```
print(newSentence)
```

Comment: +1 for a very good approach for the given task. I would of done it the exact same way, but I wanted to illustrate the problem that the OP was dealing with